# Ansible: Is there a filter to convert integer range inside a list similar to Python intspan?

Tags: ansible

Example, I have `[1-5,7,9-11]`, I'd like to have it convert to `[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11]`.

In Python, I use the module `intspan`. I cannot find this in Ansible filter.

Comment: Then you will want to [make a new filter plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) that does as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a filter in Jinja, it is way too complex [for what is meant to be a templating system and not supposed to hold lots of logic](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates).

This said, you could write some fact that could do quite the same with the help of the [`range`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#range) filter. Then you could even make this a generic task that you could [`include`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html) in any other playbook, a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html), or whatever suits you best.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    values: 1-4,8,9-11,16,36-42

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        int_span: >
          {{ 
            int_span | default([]) + 
            range(value[0] | int, value[1] | default(value[0]) | int + 1) | list 
          }}
      loop: "{{ values.split(',') }}"
      vars:
        value: "{{ item.split('-') }}"

    - debug:
        var: int_span
```

This gives:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1-4)
ok: [localhost] => (item=8)
ok: [localhost] => (item=9-11)
ok: [localhost] => (item=16)
ok: [localhost] => (item=36-42)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  int_span:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 8
  - 9
  - 10
  - 11
  - 16
  - 36
  - 37
  - 38
  - 39
  - 40
  - 41
  - 42

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks. Maybe I'll try to create my own custom filter..

Comment: by the way, I tried to create custom filter.
I cannot get it working.

`[WARNING]: Skipping plugin
(/tmp/awx_335553_5auvi_wq/project/filter_plugins/intspan_filter.py) as it seems
to be invalid: No module named 'intspan'`

I cannot install the module at target host?

Answer (score 1):

Based  on the initial comments

> *In Python, I use the module `intspan`. I cannot find this in Ansible filter.*

and the [Python documentation about `intspan` usage](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), I've created a minimal example [Custom Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins)

**`plugins/filter/int_span.py`**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from intspan import intspan

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'int_span': self.int_span,
        }

    def int_span(self, Chunks):
        return list(intspan(Chunks))
```

Regarding the mentioned error message `No module named 'intspan'` please take note to resolve the dependency via

```bash
pip install intspan
```

and use

```py
from intspan import intspan
```

The Custom Filter Plugin used with a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

     STRING: "1-3,14,29,92-97"
     LIST: [1-3,14,29,92-97]

  tasks:

  - name: Show intspan from str
    debug:
      msg: "{{ STRING | int_span }}"

  - name: Show intspan from list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST | join(',') | int_span }}"
```

it will return a list and result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show intspan from str] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 14
  - 29
  - 92
  - 93
  - 94
  - 95
  - 96
  - 97

TASK [Show intspan from list] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 14
  - 29
  - 92
  - 93
  - 94
  - 95
  - 96
  - 97
```

and runtimes of

```yaml
Show intspan from str -------- 0.10s
Show intspan from list ------- 0.08s
```

It will be faster and consume less resources than in [the other given solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67168049/6771046).

```yaml
set_fact --------------------- 0.14s
debug ------------------------ 0.08s
```

However, it moves complexity and cost of maintenance into an other domain, out of Ansible DSL, Jinja2 Templating and the playbook into the Python Custom Filter Plugin library.