# How to run Python code on the host like the 'ansible.builtin.shell' module does for Bash?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, ansible, stdout

Sometimes I cannot use the native Ansible / Jinja2 functions to get what I want, so I go get it via Bash.

For example, I had to type yesteday's date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and I found the easisest Ansible way to get it to be over complicated, being the task such a basic one

```yaml
- name: print yesterday date
  debug:
    msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime(ansible_date_time.epoch|int - 86400) }}"
```

So I wrote the following tasks to get it via Bash

```yaml
- name: Register yesterday date using Bash
  ansible.builtin.???:
    cmd: |
      echo "$(date -d 'yesterday' '+%Y-%m-%d')" 
  register: yesterday_date_bash_echo_result

- name: Show yesterday_date_bash_echo_result
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "yesterday_date_bash_echo_result.stdout is {{ yesterday_date_bash_echo_result.stdout }}"
```

Now, I would like to do the same via Python, which is even more friendly to handle when it comes to string transforming and formatting (do not focus on getting yesterday's date task, for example, think of some specific regex substitution).

So, the python commands to get yesterday's date are, for example:

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
print( datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d') )
```

How can I have my Control Machine to run them in a task so that I can register the Python output?

I would need something like the following

```yaml
- name: Register yesterday date using Python
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: |
      from datetime import datetime, timedelta
      yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
      print( datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d') )

- name: Show yesterday_date_python_echo_result
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "yesterday_date_python_echo_result.stdout is {{ yesterday_date_bash_echo_result.stdout }}"
```

Is there any builtin Ansible module to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please take note that the Python Inline Code example is not mentioned for production use but it can be helpful for Rapid Prototyping and or fast interactive testing in order to implement a Custom Filter Plugin or a Custom Module later. Furthermore, your approach is just moving costs of maintenance and operations (of code) to somewhere else.

---

> *Is there any builtin Ansible module to achieve this?*

Not directly named as such, but simply the `command` module calling the `python` executable.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Python Inline Code example
    command: /usr/bin/python
    args:
      stdin: |
        from datetime import datetime, timedelta
        yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
        print( datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d') )
    register: results

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ results.stdout }}"
```

will result into the required output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '2023-09-21'
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to get the desired output with Python Inline Code inside Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75435800/6771046)

---

**How to proceed further?**

> *Sometimes I cannot use the native Ansible / Jinja2 functions to get what I want, so I go get it via Bash.*

Right, that happens sometimes and not only to you. In such a case it is recommend to get familiar with [Developing Filter Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins). It is quite simple, see in example

- [Ansible: Is there a filter to convert integer range inside a list similar to Python `intspan`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75571474/6771046)
- [How to get the `index_max` of a list value in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75570534/6771046)
- [How to convert an AnsibleUnsafeText HEX value to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000045/6771046)
- [Is there any way to convert integer to MAC address in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74299925/6771046)

It shows if the functionality which one is looking for is not available [it can easily be created](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html).